# Date Difference, how many H D M Y have passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am building an Instagram feed with JQuery into my site and want to show how long has passed since the post was submitted in a short form like: 23H or 2D or 3M or 1Y depending on how long its been. I've got my two date objects but I can't figure our how to calculate the difference and display it how i want.

I am fairly new to JS/Jquery and as far as i could get was:

```
var pd = new Date(postDate);
var nd = new Date();
var nd = nd.getTime();
var difference = nd-pd;
```

**How do I calculate the difference between two dates in hours, days, months and years?**

Thanks.

Comment: Leap years make this significantly non-trivial.

Comment: And differing month lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing anything with dates is generally painful.
If you aren't committed to using that exact format, you can use a library for this instead.

[moment.js has a .fromnow() function.](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

or [timeago.js](http://timeago.yarp.com/) can be used to update the element on the page periodically, so if the user leaves the page open for a few minutes, the time stamps will count up.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to get the time elapsed since posted

```
var timeDiff = Math.abs(nd.getTime() - pd.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.

```
var pd = new Date(postDate);
var nd = new Date();


var Hours = nd.getHours() - pd.getHours();
var Days  = nd.getDay() - pd.getDay();
var Months = nd.getMonth() - pd.getMonth();
var Years  = nd.getYear() - pd.getYear();
```

or get millisecods diference

```
var miliseconds = (nd - pd).getTime(); //gets time  in miliseconds since 1/1/1970
```

then  use your logic to calculate hours, days, months and years

you can have a look at this [Work with a time span in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297625/work-with-a-time-span-in-javascript)
[moments](http://momentjs.com/)

ar date1 = new Date("7/Nov/2012 20:30:00");
var date2 = new Date("20/Nov/2012 19:15:00");

var diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
diff -=  days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
diff -= hours * (1000 * 60 * 60);

var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
diff -= mins * (1000 * 60);

var seconds = Math.floor(diff / (1000));
diff -= seconds * (1000);

console.log(days + " days : " + hours + " hours : " + mins + " minutes : " + seconds + " seconds");

Answer (score 0):

My solution is dirty but direct: calculate them by myself.

Record start time:

```
var BEGIN_TIME=new Date();
var HOUR=BEGIN_TIME.getHours();
var MINUTE=BEGIN_TIME.getMinutes();
var SECOND=BEGIN_TIME.getSeconds();
```

Then do so some math

```
  var today=new Date();
  h=today.getHours();
  m=today.getMinutes();
  s=today.getSeconds();

  s = s - SECOND;
  if (s<0) { s=s+60; m=m-1; }
  m = m - MINUTE;
  if (m<0) { m=m+60; h=h-1; }
  h = h - HOUR;
```