# How to get time difference between two timestamps in seconds with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, seconds, timeago

I want to display `x seconds ago` based on a MySQL Timestamp.

I found the plugin called [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

But I cannot find a way to make it display only seconds.

I'm OK with 61 seconds, or 300 seconds. Any way to convert the output to seconds with timeago, or with pure jQuery / JavaScript ?

Thanks for any help !

### Edit:

**Sample Case :**

```
$time1 = "2014-02-02 23:54:04"; // plus PHP ways to format it.
//$time2 = NOW() , or date(); whatever.
```

I just want to get how many seconds since `$time1`.

### Edit 2:

Working code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var d2 = new Date();
    var d1 = new Date("2014-02-02 23:54:04");
    $("a#timedif").html("Diff. Seconds : "+((d2-d1)/100).toString());
    // note that you may want to round the value
});
</script>
```

It outputs `Diff. Seconds : NaN`

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297625/work-with-a-time-span-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Have you managed to get the timestamp in the form of a JS object? If so, what kind of object is it?

Comment: @impinball No, but that's no problem. I can just `echo` with PHP into the `<script`> tag. **Edit:** I don't know. I will format with PHP, according to the JS function's needs.

CodeToad Thanks. An example would be a great answer !

Comment: please provide two sample date strings. see answer below for what to do after parsing.

Comment: I added the sample case. Don't have any idea how to parse into JS. Let me Google :)

Comment: why divide by 100? to get seconds from milliseconds you need one more zero. you get Nan because of string values please use new Date()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

assuming you parse the string into JavaScript date object, you can do
(date2 - date1)/1000

to parse mysql format timestamp, just feed the string into new Date():

```
 var d2 = new Date('2038-01-19 03:14:07');
 var d1 = new Date('2038-01-19 03:10:07');

 var seconds =  (d2- d1)/1000;
```

fix of edit 2 in the question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var d2 = new Date();
var d1 = new Date("2014-02-02 23:54:04");
$("a#timedif").html("Diff. Seconds : "+((d2-d1)/1000).toString());
 });
```

Comment: Almost perfect. Any way to construct d2 with the current date-time ?

Comment: current time is just new Date() no param

Comment: OMG That easy :) Let me try and accept your answer.

Comment: if you are getting one date from server and the other from client, you neeed to make sure both are in same timezone, such as UTC

Comment: Yes. Maybe I will get the date from MySQL with SELECT NOW(): **But** I'm getting NaN. please see Edit 2 in the question.

Comment: this is because you are using Date() instead of new Date(). try both in console to see difference. without 'new' you get string value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with that plugin you can modify it a little bit to work with seconds only

```
  var words = seconds < 45 && substitute($l.seconds, Math.round(seconds)) ||
    seconds < 90 && substitute($l.minute, 1) ||
    minutes < 45 && substitute($l.minutes, Math.round(minutes)) ||
    minutes < 90 && substitute($l.hour, 1) ||
    hours < 24 && substitute($l.hours, Math.round(hours)) ||
    hours < 42 && substitute($l.day, 1) ||
    days < 30 && substitute($l.days, Math.round(days)) ||
    days < 45 && substitute($l.month, 1) ||
    days < 365 && substitute($l.months, Math.round(days / 30)) ||
    years < 1.5 && substitute($l.year, 1) ||
    substitute($l.years, Math.round(years));
```

with this part, go only with converting to seconds

see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zGXLU/1/

Comment: Which plugin is that? Are you sure you didn't forget anything (like `$l` or `substitute`)? How to modify it?

Comment: this is from `timeago` plugin, its just a copy where you need to make a modification

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just a JavaScript library so JavaScript will just work within your jQuery script:

```
// specified date:
var oneDate = new Date("November 02, 2017 06:00:00");

// number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1 1970 till specified date
var oneDateMiliseconds = oneDate.getTime();

// number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1 1970 till now
var currentMiliseconds = Date.now(); 

// return time difference in milliseconds
var timePassedInMilliseconds = (currentMiliseconds-oneDateMiliseconds)/1000;
alert(timePassedInMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

My working with time difference for calculating each value separately

```
var start = new Date('Mon Jul 30 2018 19:35:35 GMT+0500');
var end = new Date('Mon Jul 30 2018 21:15:00 GMT+0500');

var hrs = end.getHours() - start.getHours();
var min = end.getMinutes() - start.getMinutes(); 
var sec = end.getSeconds() - start.getSeconds();  

var hour_carry = 0;
var minutes_carry = 0;
if(min < 0){
       min += 60;
       hour_carry += 1;
   }
hrs = hrs - hour_carry;
if(sec < 0){
       sec += 60;
       minutes_carry += 1;
   }

min = min - minutes_carry;

console.log("hrs",hrs);
console.log("min",min);
console.log("sec",sec);
console.log(hrs + "hrs " + min +"min " + sec + "sec");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get difference between two timestamps in

**Seconds:** *(get timestamp by new Date().getTime())*

```
diff_in_time = (timestamp_1 - timestamp2);
```

**In Days:**

```
diff_in_days = parseInt((timestamp_1 - timestamp2) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```