# How to get the difference between two dates in seconds in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the difference between two dates in jquery with the following code.

```
     var m = new Date();
     var dateString = m.getUTCFullYear() +"-"+ (m.getUTCMonth()+1) +"-"+ m.getUTCDate() + " " + m.getUTCHours() + ":" + m.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + m.getUTCSeconds();
                                
     var saved_time = $("#last_saved").val(); // 2021-03-02 02:39:41

     var date =  Math.abs(dateString - saved_time) / 1000;
     alert(date);
```

Getting NaN Error

Comment: try momentjs library for advanced time management.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get time difference between two timestamps in seconds with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516809/how-to-get-time-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var m = new Date();
     var dateString = Date.parse(m.getUTCFullYear() +"-"+ (m.getUTCMonth()+1) +"-"+ m.getUTCDate() + " " + m.getUTCHours() + ":" + m.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + m.getUTCSeconds());
                                
     var saved_time = Date.parse("2021-03-02 02:39:41"); // 2021-03-02 02:39:41

     var difference =  Math.abs(dateString - saved_time) / 1000;
     console.log(difference);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try to parse it before you subtract it.