# Timespan javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So i was looking for a function to get the timespan between two dates and i've found this answer on SO

[Work with a time span in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297625/work-with-a-time-span-in-javascript)

However the date is in this format `7/Nov/2012 20:30:00` and my dates are `7/11/2012 20:30:00`, and my values came from inputs

http://jsbin.com/igaruj/47/edit

If a try to change "Nov" to "11" i got NaN on the output. Do i have to convert the dates ?

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id ="start"value="7/Nov/2012 20:30:00" />

  <input type="text" id="end" value="20/Nov/2012 19:15:00" />
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript

```
var startDate = document.getElementById("start").value;
var endDate = document.getElementById("end").value;

var date1 = new Date(startDate);
var date2 = new Date(endDate);

var diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
diff -=  days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
diff -= hours * (1000 * 60 * 60);

var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
diff -= mins * (1000 * 60);

var seconds = Math.floor(diff / (1000));
diff -= seconds * (1000);


console.log(days + " days : " + hours + " hours : " + mins + " minutes : " + seconds + " seconds");
```

Comment: If you don't mind using a javascript library for it; i suggest looking into momentjs http://momentjs.com/

Comment: i was trying to do without any library if it's possible

Comment: Absolutely possible, but you will have to write a lot of the validation/parsing yourself, whereas a library has already done that for you. Look at an existing working library (like momentjs) and rewrite it to your heart's desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your 20/11/2012 20:30:00 date format:

```
var startDate = "7/11/2012 20:30:00";
var endDate = "20/11/2012 19:15:00";
```

You're getting the NaN because, it wants it in the format mm/dd/yyyy. So 20 is ofcourse an invalid month.. interchange the month and day values like:

```
var parts = startDate.split('/');
startDate = parts[1] + '/' + parts[0] + '/' + parts[2];
// 11/7/2012 20:30:00

var parts = endDate.split('/');
endDate = parts[1] + '/' + parts[0] + '/' + parts[2];
// 11/20/2012 9:15:00
```

and then do your normal time diff work and it will work:

```
var date1 = new Date(startDate);
var date2 = new Date(endDate);



var diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
diff -=  days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
diff -= hours * (1000 * 60 * 60);

var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
diff -= mins * (1000 * 60);

var seconds = Math.floor(diff / (1000));
diff -= seconds * (1000);

alert(days + " days : " + hours + " hours : " + mins + " minutes : " + seconds + " seconds");
//12 days 22 hours 45 minutes 0 seconds
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/4g1wc6ph/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript's `Date` and simply call `new Date("7/Nov/2012 20:30:00")` to get a JS Date object. Then you could extract the day, month and year using methods on that Date object.

Comment: Beware that the `Date` string constructor is inconsistent across different browsers and locales, so test thoroughly! I'd highly recommend [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) instead.

Comment: Yes, you should probably use momentjs.