# Unlimited Time inputs through HTML form

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to develop a webappliacation for project management. My requirement is to input a working time duration through a HTML form.
I was trying to use:

`<input id="appt-time" type="time" name="appt-time" required>`

But I can accept only 24 hours by using this,  But i need to input values such as 60hour 30 Minuts.

Please help if anybody have solution ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your code and explain what is not working. See best practice for [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to make it custom.

Comment: [duplicate1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127019/timefield-with-more-than-24-hours-timer), [duplicate2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098003/input-type-time-with-more-than-24-hour-options?noredirect=1&lq=1)