# How to format a time amount in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, formatting

I have a number (e.g. `567683`) that represents the amount of milliseconds a user has spent in my application. How would I format it appropriately for them? In this case, it should probably be `9 minutes and 27 seconds` (assuming an English locale, something like `9 Minuten und 27 Sekunden` would be appropriate for a German locale).

I've looked into the `Intl` API but only found timestamp formatting (like `Sun Dec 11 2019`) or relative time formatting (e.g. `24 minutes ago`). Is there a similar API (or library) just for time amounts (for lack of a better term, English isn't my native language)? It doesn't necessarily need to be international but that would still be a plus.

Comment: Check this thread: [Work with a time span in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297625/work-with-a-time-span-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Time span is just what I was looking for and moment.js looks like a suitable library.