# Convert a Javascript Audio Player timestamp to a C# TimeSpan?

Tags: javascript, c#, html5-audio

I'm not sure the best way to word this question but hoping someone can decipher what i'm asking lmao.

I have a system of timestamps in C#:

```
"beatTime": "00:00:05.0840000"
```

which gets converted to a TimeSpan via JSONDeserializer.

I am trying to make a way of capturing times in a React app using javascript, which captures time from the audio player like this:

```
"beatTime": 226.539319
```

besides the obviously stringification, i'm wondering if anyone knows the format of either the C# or javascript one so I can convert it?

Thanks...hope this kinda made sense

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` and `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` should do the converting for you.

Comment: Anyway to do it on the Javascript side?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297625/work-with-a-time-span-in-javascript